# How to send message on google plus hangout

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-plus

There is a requirement to send message from web page to google+ hangout and a email on user's email id.

AS a input only user id will be provided of user.

Is there any way to do such development.

I search around but didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [Hangout API](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/)

> The Hangouts API enables you to develop collaborative apps that run
>   inside of a Google+ Hangout. You can write your app as either a
>   [Hangout application or extension](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/publishing#types).

Read [Getting-started](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/getting-started) of `Hangouts`.